# Azure Data Factory - Add parameter to ADF linked to Git repo

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager

I have an Azure Data Factory with a linked Azure Databricks service like this:

[image]

The Databrick Workspace URL is not the same in all my environments so I need to parameterize it and include the parameter in the ARM template. I added a global parameter to the Data Factory and ticked "Include in ARM template" but when that was deployed, it removed the ADF's binding to the Git repo.

I have also tried it using the ARM Parameter Configuration:

[image]

I added this section under `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices` to the ARM template instead of using a global parameter:

```
"AzureDatabricks": {
   "properties": {
     "typeProperties": {
       "domain": "="
       }
     }
},
```

Again it removed the ADF's Git binding when it was deployed. Does anyone know a way to parameterize a field without removing the Git binding?

Comment: From the CI/CD docs:

"Adding global parameters to the ARM template adds a factory-level setting that will override other factory-level settings such as a customer-managed key or git configuration in other environments. If you have these settings enabled in an elevated environment such as UAT or PROD, it's better to deploy global parameters via a PowerShell script in the steps highlighted below."

Comment: we recently had the same requirement. Following blog helped us: https://www.keepsecure.ca/blog/fixing-adf-databricks-linked-service/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the ARM template as described in the question, I deployed and it did remove my Git binding. I added the binding back in and deployed again. Now I have both the Git binding and the parameter I needed.